# How to show recent comments on WordPress homepage with post title?

Tags: comments

I want to show 10 recent comments along with post titles on WordPress blog homepage. For this purpose, I am searching since last two days but I am unable to find any solution, Can somebody tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There's this built-in function for querying comments [`get_comments`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) and here's something that would help in your template:

```
$comments = get_comments( array( 'number' => 10 ) );

if ( !empty( $comments ) ) {

    ?>

    <ul>

    <?php foreach ( $comments as $comment ) : ?>

        <li><?php echo sprintf(

            "<strong>%s</strong> on <a href=\"%s\">%s</a> : \"%s\" &mdash; <a href=\"%s\">view</a>",
            $comment->comment_author,
            get_the_permalink( $comment->comment_post_ID ) . "#comment-" . $comment->comment_ID,
            get_the_title( $comment->comment_post_ID ),
            mb_strlen( $comment->comment_content ) > 100 ? mb_substr($comment->comment_content, 0, 100) . " .." : $comment->comment_content,
            get_the_permalink( $comment->comment_post_ID ) . "#comment-" . $comment->comment_ID

        ); ?></li>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

    </ul>

    <?php

} else {
    echo sprintf("<p>%s</p>", "No comments were found.");
}
```

If you want a short-code or a custom function and needed help, comment below.

Hope that helps.